File Preview issue
Sporadically, certain formats do not display their contents in File Preview on Windows 10. When this happens, only TXT and JPG files display. Word, Excel, and PDF files do not.
I have Googled it to my ying yang, and tried every trick in the book, to no avail. I do not want to have to re-image just for this one problem.
Anyway, I found a Band-Aid solution - I have an image of the drive from the time it used to work, which save my neck, but I still do not know what the issue is and how to fix it.
I'm confident there is someone out there who has the same problem and has found a fix.

You mean that restoring the disk from an image has fixed the problem? Did it come back? Does reboot fix it also?

Oh, I cold and warm rebooted numerous times. In fact, I turn off the computer every night but this problem has been occurring for days. Yes I restored the disc from an image and it has fixed the problem splendidly.

If the problem no longer exists, it will be hard to test suggestions for finding a solution.

I’m voting to close this question because the problem no longer exists.
